# Cloudant $regex query

Tags: regex, lucene, selector, cloudant

What are the wildcard characters that are allowed for Cloudant regex queries in selectors? For e.g, If want to to retrieve all records that contain a key `"name"` whose value begins with `"S"`. Can we write it this way:

```
"selector":{
   "name":{
       "$regex":"S*"
    }
}
```

Also, if I want to retrieve records having `"a"` as the second character in name, then can we write,

```
"selector":{
   "name":{
       "$regex":".a"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible related: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 0):

according to [Cloudant $regex query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718861/cloudant-regex-query):

> The matching algorithms that are used by the $regex operator are currently based on the Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) library External link icon. However, not all of the PCRE library is implemented. Additionally, some parts of the $regex operator go beyond what PCRE offers. For more information about what is implemented, see the Erlang Regular Expression External link icon information.

and from the [Erlang Regular Expression](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#regexp_syntax) it appears that both the asterisk and dot are implemented:

```
.   Match any character except newline
*   0 or more quantifiers
```